# Echo <style></style> in php

Tags: php, html, css

I am need to apply some style if my condition match. I have style like below

```
<style>
.adminCog {
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
    right: 11px;
    top: 8px;
    display:none;   
}
</style>
```

I want apply this only if user_id is 1

like, I have tried

```
<?php
if($user_id ==1){
echo '<style>
.adminCog {
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
    right: 11px;
    top: 8px;
    display:none;   
}
</style>';
}
```

but its not working as well not giving any error, let me know if someone can correct me. Thanks!

Comment: Instead add some class for that condition and apply that css for that class

Comment: In what way is it not working? There are no problems with the code. Perhaps `$user_id` is not actually `1` when you think it is?

Comment: Your code works perfectly well as is. https://3v4l.org/iKjVK

Comment: are you sure `display:none;` is the part of your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

**NOTE** : Check what you get in $user_id.

```
<?php
    if($user_id ==1){
?>
<style>
   .adminCog {
       z-index: 3;
       position: absolute;
       right: 11px;
       top: 8px;
       display:none;   
   }
 </style>
 <?php
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: First check what you get under the $user_id .

Comment: That should be a comment (just like the one I already made), not an answer.

Comment: Sorry But I not seen comments yet.

Comment: This is working fine. I will accept it as answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Priya there is no difference between this code and what you already have. https://3v4l.org/jQie8

Comment: $user_id = 10;  if($user_id ==10){} not use  $user_id ==1 @Nick

Comment: Solve your problem? @Priya

Comment: @DipakDholakiya it is demonstrating the fact that when `$user_id` does not match the value in the `if` then nothing is output.